# Chainlink Random Number failing with Gas error

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-vrf

I am trying to test a simple contract that uses chainlink VRF, but it fails with a GAS-related error.

- Deployed my contract to Goerli [testnet](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x7c364340b1b7d899b782b9a72eaccaf868e9bc194ee2a7aefbd9353bd74d0517)
- Sent 60 $LINK tokens to my contract
- Trying to call Get Random Number function

Here is the error that I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Can we see the code in your contract? It's hard to give an answer only with the most common error message in solidity.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error instead of posting a screenshot? Can you also list off all the steps you took?

Comment: I figured it out. There was a run-time error in my code that was causing this issue.